# Cannot start Processing from GUI

Tags: icons, gui, ide

I recently downloaded the IDE Processing. I downloaded it from the official processing Site. Then I unzipped the Data and put it in my home directory.

One extra folder "processing-3.2.1/" with core, Java, lib, the program itself, and all that stuff.

I can start it without any issues from the terminal but **my problems are**:

- it has no icon, it shows a question mark.
- if i want to start it from the GUI it says: `An error occurred while starting the application`.

I don't know why it starts perfectly from terminal but not from GUI ???

Comment: Since you installed it locally and you mention *" if i want to start it from the GUI it says:..."* , there must be a corresponding .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`. That one is probably created when you chose "lock to launcher", and has "unity" in its name. Please post the content of the file, the command you run the application with. Additionally; did you also download an icon?

Comment: Jes, there is actually no: "processing.desktop" file. How do i create this file ?

I run pocessing with : " ./processing-2.3.1/processing

 The processing-3.2.1 folder has a lib subfolder an there are several icons.